# django-social-auth redirect_uri invalid

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get django-social-auth working. My dev server is a server in a private network at my work, accessed by a 10.0.0.* IP Address. We have multiple django apps running on this server. Here's the config I have for this app:

```
# Perceptual
location /perceptual/static/ {
        alias /opt/perceptual/perceptual/static/;
}
location /perceptual/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

I'm running a backbone.js app out of my static directory with this. So, I can go to 10.0.0.54/perceptual/static/, and get my backbone app.

**NOW,** I have my Facebook APP_ID and FACEBOOK_API_SECRET in my settings file, all correctly configured. I also have a line in my /etc/hosts file on my *actual* machine (not the dev server) that directs **myapp.com** to **10.0.0.54**, and my Facebook app config for the App Domains and Site URL look like this:

```
App Domains: perceptual.com
Site URL: http://perceptual.com
```

The problem is, whenever I go to perceptual.com/perceptual/static/login/facebook/ it gives me this error:
[image: Facebook Error (django-social-auth)]

Here's what my URL looks like when I get that error:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&state=PC0OhXnEuaW2wcUuINO0rMSMAtVDuMbn&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8001%2Fperceptual%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F%3Fredirect_state%3DPC0OhXnEuaW2wcUuINO0rMSMAtVDuMbn&client_id=419178148154217

So you can see from the URL that my redirect_uri is `http://localhost:8001` - But I don't want it to be that, obviously. As soon as I change it to perceptual.com, it gets a bit farther: Then I get this error:

```
AuthFailed at /perceptual/complete/facebook/
Authentication failed: There was an error authenticating the app
```

Here's my [traceback, if it helps](http://pastebin.com/UVE6Eqft)

At this point, I'm stuck - How do I get my server to change the redirect_uri to something that Facebook can handle, instead of 127.0.0.1:8000? My guess is that it's coming from Django, but I'm not sure how to change it. Then, once that's fixed, it still can't fully authenticate, and gets the error stated above. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

django-social-auth uses `request.build_absolute_uri()` to build that `redirect_uri` parameter. Checking django code for [`build_absolute_uri()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L100) it calls [`get_host()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L51) which checks for `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST`, `HTTP_HOST` or `SERVER_NAME`.

Try defining any of those headers in your location recipe (I think there's a `proxy_set_header` for that).

Comment: Thank you, omab! I was able to set this config in my nginx config file:
`proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host 'xxxxx.com';`
and in my django settings.py file:
`USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True`
And that got it all working. Thanks again!

Comment: @JamesRasmussen yep, `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` was the bit I was missing too. Thanks.

Comment: also here are settings related to reverse proxy situation : http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#processing-redirects-and-urlopen

Comment: @JamesRasmussen instructions together with omab's answer worked just fine to me
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment. The above discussion helped clarify for me the issue of managing nginx headers for making Django allauth social authentication work correctly for redirect-URI callback issues.

However, the solution proposed in [this discussion on github](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/85) worked better for me. There was no need to use `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True`.

```
location / {
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_pass      http://localhost:8000;
}
```