# Python-social-auth using Django server hostname and listening port as redirect_uri

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth

I'm using python-social-auth with Django to authenticate with Google using Oauth2 (google-oauth2). In my template I use something [like](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/examples/django_example/example/templates/home.html):

```
<a href="{% url "begin:social" "google-oauth2" %}">Login</a>
```

And it correctly creates an `A` element pointing to the correct login url. The thing is, django is running with `runserver` option behind Apache with `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` (also tried nginx with `proxy_pass` option, not fcgi).

In this scenario I have two problems; first, when creating the authentication request, python-social-auth sends the parameter `redirect_uri` as `localhost:8000` so I did this on settings.py:

```
AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'redirect_uri': 'http://myapp.com'}
```

And it bypasses the "Bad Request" Google response that is returned if I send `localhost:8000` as redirect_uri.

Then, in python-social-auth `oauth.py`, [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/oauth.py#L319), I can see that

```
self.auth_complete_params(self.validate_state())
```

Is sending the same wrong `redirect_uri` to Google. So I did something ugly like:

```
data = self.auth_complete_params(self.validate_state())
data['redirect_uri'] = 'http://myapp.com'
response = self.request_access_token(
    self.ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
    data=data, # ugh!
    headers=self.auth_headers(),
    method=self.ACCESS_TOKEN_METHOD
)
```

So, that's my current solution. I just don't understand on how to do this on a more elegant way, or the "correct" way.

Any help out there?

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got that right, the problem is that python-social-auth is creating the wrong redirect_uri to send to the auth provider. It always sends `http://localhost:8000/my-login-page` but you want it to send `http://myapp.com/my-login-page` .

The right place to specify the redirect URI is in settings.py:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'http://myapp.com/my-login-url'
```

and similar settings for special cases (e.g. SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL). Then, you need to tell python-social-auth to let you change the domain, otherwise it will force the domain back to `localhost:8000`. Do this:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_SANITIZE_REDIRECTS = False
```

(It is also possible to fix this *across all of Django* by giving hints to its `build_absolute_uri()` method about what domain to use. This involves more pieces of your stack but check it out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13788571/8735)).

Comment: Extra tip: Add `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` to your settings.py to allow Django to check the X_FORWARDED_HOST value to obtain the real host.

Comment: Defining any of the URLs settings with a FQDN and disable sanitizing is not the right approach. Use `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` as mentioned by @MichaelButler.

Answer (score -1):

I have Django 1.9 and python-socail-auth 0.2.13

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'social.apps.django_app.default',
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = True
RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '***'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '***'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',  
'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  url(r'', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
  url(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
]
```

In template:

```
 <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={% url 'dashboard' %}">Google</a> |
```

Google Developers Console -> App -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs-> Client ID for Web application:

```
Authorized JavaScript origins: 
  http://127.0.0.1:8000

Authorized redirect URIs: 
  http://127.0.0.1:8000
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/google-oauth2/
```