# Django Social Auth redirect to url with Port number

Tags: django, facebook, apache, redirect, nginx

I hope somebody can help me because im struggling with the facebook redirects from the django_social_auth app.

The problem is that it keeps me redirecting with the port number included:

1. http://mywebsite.com/login/facebook
2. http://mywebsite.com:8080/complete/facebook/

The thing is that i'm running a Nginx/apache configuration for my django project.

- Nginx for statics/medias which is on port 80 and a proxypath to 8080
- Apache on port 8080

I digged into the social_auth code and it seems that it uses request.get_host()
to determine the redirects ( which obviously  contains the port )

What would be the most clever way to handle the situation ?

- Reconfigure apache and nginx and switch their ports?
- Write a middleware that strips out the port number?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782979/django-social-auth-redirect-uri-invalid)? It suggests using an nginx proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host because that's how django_social_auth builds the redirect_uri.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Charlie who pointed me to the right direction.

The only thing i had to do was add this line to my nginx server config:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

and this like to the django settings

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
```

Now it works perfectly

Comment: You probably meant `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;` - the Host header does not include the port number, and is not influenced by `USE_X_FORWARDED_FOR`